# Showing output both with Jupyter notebook and in python interactive at same time?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

I imagine this question is rather silly.

I'm using VS code and Jupyter notebooks within it.  Is it possible to have the output sent to the interactive python interpreter instead/at the same time as the output beneath the Jupyter notebook cells?  I tried searching, google but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in short is unfortunately 'no'. The Interactive window can be used with the `#%%` magic line or using the 'Jupiter.execSelectionInteractive' command (`⇧ + ↩` on Mac). However, the later is not available in a notebook, only in `.py` files.